# Global exception hadling .net core doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I try to apply global exeption handling in project. I think that I have everything set properly:

Middleware:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}");
}
```

ErrorController:

```
[AllowAnonymous] 
[Route("Error")] 
public IActionResult Error() 
{returnView("Error");}
```

View is set as well.

I try to throw new Exception("message") in controllers, middleware, models but everytime my app falls down with message unhandled exception. In Launch setting is set Production. Even is Development I cannot see DeveloperExceptionPage... But during the writing code when some error appaered DeveloperExceptionPage worked well...

Thank you in advance for helping.

D.

Comment: The application needs to see the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Comment: Hi, Enviroment is set in launchSettings properly. But even is env set as Development or Production app falls down :/

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean the app falls down?  I assumed your question was about how to get the the developer exception page to show.  Can you please clarify and provide the actual exception you get?

Comment: You're probably throwing an exception some place that cannot be caught by the middleware, i.e. (`Program`, `Startup` or some other piece of middleware included before the exception handling middleware). "Global" in this case means "for all requests", not necessarily any exception thrown by your app, especially those occurring outside the request pipeline. It would help if you posted the actual exception you're getting along with the stack trace.

Comment: If I throw an exception (throw new exception) anywhere in controller or model is not caught in ExceptionHandler (env Production) or by DeveloperExceptionPage. See the example:                                              
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(EmployeeEditViewModel model)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception in Edit");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)                                                                         But when some other exception occured during writing code, it was caught by DeveloperExceptionPage succesfully